# How to convert 2d array into html file in bash/shell?

Tags: html, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script in which I have my data in 2d array now currently I am printing this matrix as follows:

```
f1="%$((${#num_rows}+1))s"
  f2=" %12s"

  printf "$f1" ''

      printf "$f2" "Total"
      printf "$f2" "Pass"
      printf "$f2" "Stillfail"
      printf "$f2" "Failure"
      printf "$f2" "APIName"
      printf "$f2" 
 echo 
  for ((j=1;j<=num_rows;j++)) do
      printf "$f1" $j
      for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
          if [ i == 5 ]; then
            printf "%-20s" ${matrix[$j,$i]}
          else
            printf "$f2" ${matrix[$j,$i]}
      done
      echo
  done
```

I tried a lot but still there is alignment problem so now I want to create a html table to output this data.Can anyone guide me on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add table, tr and td markers where you are currently printing the data?

Comment: I tried that also but unfortunately that won't work in bash script

Comment: "<table style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Stillfail</th>
      <th>Pass</th>
      <th>ScriptError</th>
      <th>APIName</th>
    </tr>"
    echo
     for ((j=1;j<=num_rows;j++)) do
        printf "<tr>"
        for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
              printf "<td>" ${matrix[$j,$i]} "</td>"
        printf "</tr>"
        done
      echo
     done
  "</table>"

Comment: So what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete script. I think this will fix the issue

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a matrix
num_rows=6
num_columns=5

for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<=num_rows;j++)) do
        matrix[$i,$j]=$RANDOM
    done
done

f1="%$((${#num_columns}+3))s"
f2=" %12s"

header=( "" "Total" "Pass" "Stillfail" "Failure" "APIName" )

printf "$f1|" 'No.'
for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
  if [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
    printf "%-20s|" ${header[$i]}
  else
    printf "$f2|" ${header[$i]}
  fi
done
echo

for ((j=1;j<=num_rows;j++)) do
    printf "$f1|" $j
    for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
      if [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
        printf "%-20s|" ${matrix[$j,$i]}
      else
        printf "$f2|" ${matrix[$j,$i]}
      fi
    done
    echo
done

echo
echo  "-----HTML----"
echo "<table style="width:50%">"

printf "$f1" '<tr><th>No.</th>'
for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
  if [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
    printf "<th align=left>%s</th>" ${header[$i]}
  else
    printf "<th align=right>%s</th>" ${header[$i]}
  fi
done
echo '</tr>'

for ((j=1;j<=num_rows;j++)) do
    printf "<tr><td align=right>$f1</td>" $j
    for ((i=1;i<=num_columns;i++)) do
      if [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
        printf "<td align=left>%s</td>" ${matrix[$j,$i]}
      else
        printf "<td align=right>%s</td>" ${matrix[$i,$j]}
      fi
    done
    echo '</tr>'
done
echo "</tr></table>"
```